# how to query a table using name from another column from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get data from a table where the table name is stored in another table.
I am trying for select query but not able to get the data.

example

```
t1
table name | some data

t2 - table name is same coming from t1
t2
id | some data
```

I need to fetch the t2 name first from t1 that I am able to do. but using that query response I am not sure how to fetch the second query as the result is coming from first query.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you writing a store procedure? You should search for Dynamic SQL

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to store table or column names in tables - unless you are writing a DBMS. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It'll have to be some kind of "dynamic" SQL. One option is to create a function that returns ref cursor. Here's an example.

This is your `t1` table; it contains some table names.

```
SQL> select * from tname;

        ID TABLE_NAME
---------- ---------------
         1 emp
         2 dept
```

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_tab (par_table_name in varchar2)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open rc for 'select * from ' || dbms_assert.sql_object_name(par_table_name);
  7    return rc;
  8  end;
  9  /

Function created.
```

Testing: query selects table names from the `tname` table and returns their contents:

```
SQL> select f_tab(t.table_name) result
  2  from tname t
  3  order by t.id;

RESULT
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE                   SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17.12.1980 00:00:00        800                    20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20.02.1981 00:00:00       1600        300         30
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22.02.1981 00:00:00       1250        500         30
      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02.04.1981 00:00:00       2975                    20
      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28.09.1981 00:00:00       1250       1400         30
      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01.05.1981 00:00:00       2850                    30
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09.06.1981 00:00:00       2450                    10
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 09.12.1982 00:00:00       3000                    20
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17.11.1981 00:00:00       5000                    10
      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08.09.1981 00:00:00       1500          0         30
      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 12.01.1983 00:00:00       1100                    20
      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03.12.1981 00:00:00        950                    30
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03.12.1981 00:00:00       3000                    20
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23.01.1982 00:00:00       1300                    10

14 rows selected.

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON


SQL>
```